# Minishift: Unsupported docker v1 repository request for docker

Tags: minishift

I am getting the following error when trying to deploy a local Docker image to a pod in my local Minishift instance:

```
Failed to pull image "repo-name:port/app-name:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-20190103151332485": 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: 
Status 400 trying to pull repository app-name: 
"{\n \"errors\" : [ {\n \"status\" : 400,\n \"message\" : 
\"Unsupported docker v1 repository request for 'docker'\"\n } ]\n}"
```

I have successfully deployed other pods locally using the same Docker environment.

Running `docker images` I can confirm my image exists locally.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this error can appear for a variety of reasons. Most commonly it seems to be due to invalid credentials or an issue communicating with a remote repository.

If you are certain your issue is not with remote communication, **the problem might be that your image is failing to start.** I have not had a chance to look into it but a better error message for this would be a great contribution to [Minishift](https://github.com/minishift/minishift), if possible.

### Test Docker Image Manually

To verify your docker image is working, try to run it manually.

#### Find the Image

Run: `$ docker images`

You should see a list that contains the image Minishift is trying to deploy. For example:

```
REPOSITORY                TAG                                IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
repo-name:port/app-name   1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-20190103151332485   3e050126264c        14 minutes ago      704MB
repo-name:port/app-name   1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-20190103150418331   4293956e114f        23 minutes ago      704MB
repo-name:port/app-name   1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-20190103145227835   81fc7783e38f        35 minutes ago      704MB
repo-name:port/app-name   1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-20190103145203603   c5fa4815ee97        35 minutes ago      704MB
```

#### Run the Image

Once you have identified the Image ID of the image you are trying to deploy, run:

`$ docker run -i -t <Image ID> /bin/bash`

For example:

`$ docker run -i -t 3e050126264c /bin/bash`

### Diagnosis

If the image fails with an error, you have likely located the problem with your Minishift deploys. Diagnose the issue until you have a healthy image then try to deploy again.

In my personal instance, I find it most reliable to delete the old application from Minishift before deploying a healthy version.